# Error: Please make sure `y` is a factor or numeric value

Tags: r

I am new here as well as to R.  I have been reading responses to similar questions but none seem to fix my problem.

My code is as follows:

```
labelName <- 'TERM'
predictors <- names(ensembleData)[names(ensembleData) != labelName]
myControl <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=3, repeats=1, returnResamp='none')
model_glm <- train(ensembleData[,predictors], ensembleData[,labelName], method='glm', trControl=myControl)
```

But I am still getting the 'y' as factor or numeric value issue.  When I run `str(test)`, all show as `factor` or num.

Can anyone provide me some advice?  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Enter dput(head(your_data)) into your R code, then post the output in your question. This enables someone to copy your data, to try and reproduce (and then fix) the error.

Comment: Uhh, I think you have put the dependent variable and the predictors in the wrong position? `model_glm <- train(ensembleData[,labelName], ensembleData[,predictors], method='glm', trControl=myControl)` see if this works?